# multiline regex

Tags: python, regex

I am having some trouble searching for a multiline pattern using regex. Here is the sample multiline string:

```
some command [first line]\n
second line \n
yes can have multiple lines\n
\n
something else that I do not care about.
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
>>> match = re.match(r"^(.+)\n((.*\n)*)\n",body,re.MULTILINE)
>>> match.groups()
('some command [first line]', 'second line \nyes can have multiple lines\n', 'yes can have multiple lines\n')
```

I am looking for match.group(1) and match.group(2), and I am happy with them, but it is bugging me that I get `match.group(3)` which I do not expect (and makes me this that my regexp is not right).

Also, I do not seem to get named patterns right..

```
 match = re.match(r"^(.+)\n((?P<bd>.*\n)*)\n",body,re.MULTILINE)
 >>> match.group(bd)
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 NameError: name 'bd' is not defined
```

I went through the [Python Regular Expressions from Google](http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/regular-expressions.html), but it is obvious that I have not gotten the complete picture yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did I understand you right, that the result that you expect is in group 3 instead of group2?

If that is your problem, you can make groups non-capturing by putting a `?:` at the start like this

```
re.match(r"^(.+)\n(?:(.*\n)*)\n",body,re.MULTILINE)
```

With this you will get only two groups in the result.

Maybe I got you wrong and you want to get rid of the group 3, then

```
re.match(r"^(.+)\n((?:.*\n)*)\n",body,re.MULTILINE)
```

would be the solution.

**Named groups**

You can access your named group like this

```
m.group('bd')
```

you need to give `group()` either a integer or a string as argument, see [MatchObject](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MatchObject)